# Stop pydoc from running my Python program

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pydoc

Following on "[Windows 7 - pydoc from cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149274/windows-7-pydoc-from-cmd)", I have the following problem. I prepared a simple, docstring-documented hello.py "hello world" script:

```
""" This module prints Hello, world
    More documentation.
"""
print("Hello, world")
```

and saved it in C:\Python34\lib.

Then using Window's command-line, I changed the directory to C:\Python34\lib, and ran

```
pydoc <full path to hello.py>
```

My output is:

```
Hello, world
Help on module hello:

NAME
    hello

DESCRIPTION
    This module prints Hello, world
    More documentation.

FILE
    c:\python34\lib\hello.py
```

It's great that it printed the documentation, but first it ran the program.

How do I get it to NOT run the program, just print the documentation?

Comment: IIRC, That's not how it works ... `pydoc` (and a number of other auto-documentation tools e.g.  `sphinx`) import the source and look for the `__doc__` attributes that python adds to classes/functions, etc.  The only tool that I know of which _doesn't_ import the source is `epydoc`.  That said, usually you can guard any statements that you don't want to execute in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Answer (score 8):

`pydoc` imports the module to be documented. So statements there are executed.

If you can modify the code, guard the `print` line with `if __name__ == "__main__"` so the line is executed only when it is executed directly, but not when it is imported:

```
""" This module prints Hello, world
    More documentation.
"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello, world")
```

Comment: `__name__` doesn't change whether I import the module or run it with pydoc. I can't find any info on what changes when pydoc is run.

Comment: @nurettin, Let's say the file is `abcd.py`. Then, `__name__` of the module is `abcd` if you import it or run it with pydoc.`__name__` is `__main__` if you run (not import) it with `python` directly. https://docs.python.org/library/__main__.html

Comment: that's right, and it makes no difference whether we import or run with pydoc.